# Depending on fairly big modules to do just a simple operation

Tags: python

So I have a website which does a bunch of different stuff, more importantly, it allows the user to upload videos.

Now unfortunately videos are a bit annoying as they need a poster img to display correctly on mobile (I'm looking at you Safari...), so anyways, I made a nice function that uses Moviepy to extract the first frame and then Pillow to process it (basically just adding the duration of the video in the bottom right corner).

So I'm wondering, is this good practice? I feel like depending on those big and clunky modules may generate vulnerabilities, for example, what happens if an user provides a malformed mp4 which then gets processed? It feels very risky, but again I am unsure how I would approach this problem without those extra tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically have no choice. Extracting and manipulating a frame from a video stream isn't a simple operation that you might just code yourself. The libraries being used are hopefully well-tested and safer than something you could come up with, and vulnerabilities should be fixed within short time after being found.

However, if your code depends on such potentially vulnerable libraries, you should take some precautions:

- Monitor the change logs of those libraries to notice when security-related issues are found and fixed, and rebuild your application with the fixed version.
- If possible, process external files in a sandbox which should prevent malicious code from doing harm to your whole system.